# Maintenance Complexity of Gradle build scripts

Tags: complexity, build-system, gradle

I am currently trying out Gradle for my embedded development project. The existing tool is GNU Make. Across the internet I have read a lot of articles where people say that their build logic becomes "too complex" and they would like to reduce "complexity". This I believe is basically a developer's or build author's perception of complexity of build scripts. Are there any ways to formally express complexity of build logic? I did a bit of digging and came up with [this](http://research.cs.queensu.ca/home/cordy/Papers/MC_WETSOM16_Complexity.pdf) for Makefiles complexity. Is there already an existing measure for `build.gradle`'s complexity?

Comment: I have never seen complex gradle scripts but i have seen lots of complex ant and make scripts. Since gradle is declarative (i.e. you have to define **what** you need but **not how to do it** and there are sub-modules (aka "plugins") that translate the "what" into how.. I am not shure if complex(=spagetti-code) gradle scripts exist

Comment: @k3b worse, that means the plugin is part of your script and the plugins are always leaky abstractions. That makes the overall complexity very high.

Answer (score -1):

There is the `--profile` option:

> If we want to know more about how much time is spent in tasks we can use the --profile command-line option. Gradle will generate a report file in the build/reports/profile directory. This report file is a HTML file with information about how much time is spent by the different tasks and processes of Gradle.

As well as the [gradle profiler](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-profiler):

> A tool to automate the gathering of profiling and benchmarking information for Gradle builds. Profiling information can be captured using several different tools...

**References**

- [Command-Line Interface - Gradle User Manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_performance)
- [gradle performance test suite](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/performance)
- [Improving the Performance of Gradle Builds](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/)